# Accessing stored data from a function-structure code

Tags: c, function, struct

In the main function, the user must enter an ID. Then the inputted ID data will be displayed (the student's name, ID, and course).

I need to code the missing part that must aim to compare the user's inputted 'ID' to the ID stored from the function 'populate()' and then how will it display the data from the multiple structs inside the function?

Is it possible to access Struct Student s1 - s10 as variable?
like;
if(id == '1001'){
printf("Student ID: %s\nStudent Name: %s\nCourse: %s", student s1);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student {
    char id[4];
    char name[8];
    char course[5];
};

void populate() {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("students.csv", "w");

    struct Student s1 = {"1001", "John", "BSCS"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s1.id, s1.name, s1.course);

    struct Student s2 = {"1002", "Bob", "BSIT"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s2.id, s2.name, s2.course);

    struct Student s3 = {"1003", "Jane", "BSIT"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s3.id, s3.name, s3.course);

    struct Student s4 = {"1004", "Karla", "BSIT"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s4.id, s4.name, s4.course);

    struct Student s5 = {"1005", "Clarisse", "BSCS"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s5.id, s5.name, s5.course);

    struct Student s6 = {"1006", "Peter", "BSCS"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s6.id, s6.name, s6.course);

    struct Student s7 = {"1007", "Bob", "BSCS"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s7.id, s7.name, s7.course);

    struct Student s8 = {"1008", "Stewie", "BSIT"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s8.id, s8.name, s8.course);

    struct Student s9 = {"1009", "Bryan", "BSCS"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s9.id, s9.name, s9.course);

    struct Student s10 = {"1010", "Kent", "BSIT"};
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s10.id, s10.name, s10.course);

    fclose(fp);
}

void display(const char* id) {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("students.csv", "r");

    struct Student student;
    if (strcmp(student.id, id) == 0) {
        printf("Student Id: %s\n", student.id);
        printf("Student Name: %s\n", student.name);
        printf("Course: %s\n", student.course);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

int main() {
    populate();

    char id[4];

    printf("Enter student_id: ");
    fgets(id, 4, stdin);

    display(id);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code needs to be posted here otherwise I'd say it's quite difficult to figure out what's going on!

Comment: yea, sorry. I've edited it already.

Comment: *the ID stored from the function 'populate()'*  Oh?  What do you think happens to all those `struct Student` variables - `s1` through `s10` - when the `populate()` function returns?

Comment: oh I think s1 - s10 will all be accessed since I don't have a condition for it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, the string `"1001"` requires **5** bytes of memory. You must always account for the null-terminating byte (`'\0'`) at the end of a string. In memory it looks like:

```
'1' | '0' | '0' | '1' | '\0'
```

Your structure definition

```
struct Student {
    char id[4];
    char name[8];
    char course[5];
};
```

will not have enough space to store these [*strings*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/bytehttps://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte). A caveat of C is that arrays (e.g., `char id[4];`) may be [*initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) by string literals that are one byte too large. The resulting array will omit the null-terminating byte, and you will no longer have a string.

So while the structure initialization works, the following

```
fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%s\n", s1.id, s1.name, s1.course);
```

immediately invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by passing something that is not a string to the `printf` specifier `%s`.

And here

```
char id[4];
printf("Enter student_id: ");
fgets(id, 4, stdin);
```

`id` will always be too small to store any of the IDs that would be written to the file in `populate`, as `fgets` always null-terminates the buffer on success. Additionally, if `fgets` reads a newline character, that too will be stored in the buffer.

---

> Is it possible to access `struct Student` `s1` - `s10` as variable?

The variables `s1` through `s10` represent objects of [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). They exist only for the [duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) of their enclosing *block*, which in this case is the function call `populate`. When the function returns, they no longer exist.

But you seem to be confusing two concepts:

- Do you want persistent program memory that can be accessed by different function calls?
- Or, do you want to write data to a file and later retrieve it?

If you want the former, you should declare your variables in `main` and pass pointers to these objects to your different functions. Alternatively, the variables can be defined "globally" at [file scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope).

If you want the latter, then `display` needs to actually read information from the file it opens (`fp`). Right now, `struct Student student;` is an uninitialized structure, and reading its members (as in `strcmp(student.id, id)`) invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

---

Aside: any time you find yourself enumerating variable names (`s1`, `s2`, `s3`, ...), you should ask yourself if an *array* would not be more appropriate.

---

It seems most likely that you are looking to write to a file, and then search the contents of the file.

Consider the following condensed example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student {
    char id[16];
    char name[32];
    char course[32];
};

int write_to_file(const char *fname)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fname, "w");

    if (!file) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 0;
    }

    struct Student students[] = {
        { "1001", "John", "BSCS" },
        { "1002", "Bob", "BSIT" },
        { "1003", "Jane", "BSIT" },
        { "1004", "Karla", "BSIT" },
        { "1005", "Clarisse", "BSCS" },
        { "1006", "Peter", "BSCS" },
        { "1007", "Bob", "BSCS" },
        { "1008", "Stewie", "BSIT" },
        { "1009", "Bryan", "BSCS" },
        { "1010", "Kent", "BSIT" }
    };

    size_t length = sizeof students / sizeof *students;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int rc = fprintf(file, "%s,%s,%s\n",
                    students[i].id,
                    students[i].name,
                    students[i].course);

        if (rc < 0) {
            perror("fprintf");
            fclose(file);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 1;
}

void find_in_file_by_id(const char *fname, const char *id)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fname, "r");

    if (!file) {
        perror("fopen");
        return;
    }

    int success = 0;
    struct Student student;

    while (3 == fscanf(file, "%15[^,],%31[^,],%31[^\n]\n",
                student.id, student.name, student.course)) {
        if (0 == strcmp(student.id, id)) {
            printf("Found student: <%s> <%s> <%s>\n",
                    student.id,
                    student.name,
                    student.course);
            success = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    if (!success)
        fprintf(stderr, "Student ID <%s> not found.\n", id);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *file_name = "students.csv";

    if (!write_to_file(file_name))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    char input[256];

    printf("Enter student ID: ");

    if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0'; /* remove the newline */

    find_in_file_by_id(file_name, input);
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter student ID: 1004
Found student: <1004> <Karla> <BSIT>
$ ./a.out
Enter student ID: 1234
Student ID <1234> not found.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need, I will make effort to study and understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

Variables with storage auto are allocated on the stack by the compiler. Also they have the scope of the block they are declared in.
Thus these variables (s1-s10) are not accessible outside of the populate function. Also they are deallocated, if you return from that function.
If you want them to still persists afterwards you have to allocate them somewhere else. If you want them accessible from the outside, you can pass a pointer to them somewhere, but that doesn't solve the deallocation problem. If you would return a pointer to a local variable, you would get undefined behavior, as the variable will be deallocated and the pointer would be dangling (pointing to nonsense).
So you have two options:

- allocated them somewhere else on the stack:

```
int main()
{
    struct Student students[10];
    populate (&students);
[...]
}

void populate(struct Student * students)
{
    students[0] = {"1001", "John", "BSCS"};
[...]
}
```

- allocate them on the heap instead:

```
struct Students *
populate ()
{
    struct Students * students;

    students = malloc (sizeof (struct Students) * 10);
    if (NULL == students) abort();
    
    students[0] = {"1001", "John", "BSCS"};
[...]
    return students;
}
```

As a third way you could also declare them with global scope, but I wouldn't recommend that. (unless you are just a bit hacking, but not for something real)

Note that I changed your 10 variables into one array, because otherwise you have to pass 10 separate pointers around.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge! But I don't think that I can change the 10 variables 'cause its a given from the question. I can only edit in the main.

Comment: @Reece What question?  That restriction seems misguided given the code you've posted here.  Because the `populate()` function stores **nothing**.

Comment: Sorry for not being good with words use, I mean the populate function must not be edited.  I must only code on the main function, where the inputted ID must call and print the data the ID itself contains.

Comment: @reece - you need to read the data from the file the populate function creates, apparently.